# Trying to get liked property of page object from Facebook signed request but object doesn't exist

Tags: c#, facebook

I'm trying to restrict content on a canvas app to users who have liked the page.  To do this we're decoding the signed_request and using the liked property of the page object.  The problem I have is that as part of my testing, I removed the app from my facebook account and now whenever I try to go to the page, the signed_request comes back without a page object, so I see my page that tells visitors to like the page, however, there is no like button on the page anymore as it has already been liked.

Has anyone seen this before and is there a sensible way to handle this situation that I'm not seeing?

It sounds very similar to the issue described in [How to get the if the Page is Liked in my Facebook Application page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886775/how-to-get-the-if-the-page-is-liked-in-my-facebook-application-page) but I'm decoding the signed request using the application secret and I am seeing values for other objects like so:

`{"algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256","issued_at":1317741105,"user":{"country":"gb","locale":"en_GB","age":{"min":21}}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you confusing terminology here? If it's a canvas app, there won't be a `page` parameter in the signed request, and you'll need to make an explicit API call to check if a user likes a page.

The `page` parameter in the signed request will only be present on app page loads which come via your app's presence as a tab on a Facebook Page

Comment: Found the problem, and yes.  I was mixed up.  The problem was that I was trying the URL for the app when I needed the URL for the page which, as you've correctly pointed out, won't give me a page object.